# Generate XPath expression of Google search engine

Tags: java, xpath, jdom

What XPath expression should I use to parse Google XHTML results page? I'm not able to retrieve it using

```
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile(".//li[@class='g']/div/h3/em/text()");
```

Comment: Don't parse their website, but use their [Custom Search API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/dev_guide) instead. This is much more robust as their website that changes all the time, and Google will block your IP if you're sending too many queries over the website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's XHTML, you probably need a namespace binding on the expression

```
Namspace ns = NAmespave.getNamespace("x", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml");
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile(
    ".//x:li[@class='g']/x:div/x:h3/x:em/text()", null, null, ns);
```

Comment: thanks! I'll check it out later! for now google returns 403 code!

Comment: 403 says "forbidden", possibly a problem with what I wrote in my comment on your question. :)

Comment: In addition, I'd like to ask you one more question! Let's assume that <span></span> has several <b></b> tags inside. How can I get those which are in <b> and also the text itself. E.g. `<span>This text <b> is bold </b> and <b>Bold text is here also</b></span>`  I am doing using this kind of expression - `/span/text()` and it returns only `This text` but I want all of those including texts in <b> tag. How can I do this using xpath??